# Redirect domain and subpage in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a domain to another domain, which works ok.
But if I try to redirect a specific url to another url on another domain, it doesn't work.

E.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^christmas?$ https://www.example.com/pages/christmas.html [L,R=301]
```

But all I get is it redirects to the current domain.

Comment: "all I get is it redirects to the current domain" - Are you sure there is actually a "redirect", or is the directive simply not doing anything? If it redirected to the same URL on the same domain then you'd get a redirect-loop and the request would fail. It sounds like you probably have a conflict with other directives. What URL are you trying to match? `^christmas?$` - with this you are making the `s` _optional_ - is that really the intention? Presumably "another domain" is on a different server?

Comment: @MrWhite bascially the christmas is a url: https://currentdomain.nl/christmas and this needs to redirect to https://www.example.com/pages/christmas.html. I am not very used to htaccess, so not sure if I do it in the correct way.

Comment: So you are seeing an external redirect to `https://currentdomain.nl/pages/christmas.html`?! Please confirm the HTTP status in the network traffic. The directive you posted cannot possibly do that, so there must be _something else_ going on here. eg. a conflict with existing directives. Please include your entire `.htaccess` file in your question. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?